# Java multi-client -server message doesnt display

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I'm asking client to write the login and server should display it on the screen as the first word from the whole message from the client.
The problem is nothing shows on the screen while server receives the message from the client.

```java
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ip = "127.0.0.1";
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip,7010);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Write your login:");
            String toSend;
            String arr[];
            while (true) {
                toSend = scanner.nextLine();
                arr = toSend.split(" ",2);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                out.write("$login " + arr[0]);
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the Client code

```java
public class Server {
    public static ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7010);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("A new client is connected");
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");
                ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(socket,out,in);
                client.start();
                clients.add(client);
                System.out.println("Hello");
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                socket.close();
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket socekt;
    private OutputStreamWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket, OutputStreamWriter out, BufferedReader in) {
        this.socekt = socket;
        this.out = out;
        this.in = in;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String receivedName;
        try {
            receivedName = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(receivedName);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd edit of the code, server still doesn't print the login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tray to keep the client socket alive and your ClientHandler.
Wrap everything efter *System.out.println("Write your login:");* into a while loop. Also add "\n" to the out because you are using readline. Next add *out.flush()* at the end of the loop like so.

```
String toSend;
String arr[];
while (true) {
    toSend = scanner.nextLine();
    arr[] = toSend.split(" ", 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // debug
    out.write("$login " + arr[0] +  + "\n");
    out.flush();
}
```

Regarding ClientHandler Server create a global ArrayList and add all created clients. Something like this,

```
public class Server {
 ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
 
 public void add(ClientHandler c) {
     clients.add(c);
     System.out.println("Server added client!");
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Server server = new Server();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7010);
    Socket socket = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(socket,out,in);
            client.start();
            server.add(client);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            socket.close();
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in ClientHandler remove the public static *ArrayList clients;* and *ClientHandler.clients.add(receivedName);*

Regarding the out I personally like to use OutputStreamWriter. And I declare them like so;

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
clientSocket.setSoTimeout(30000); // some time out
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: I have changed the code according to your directions, still doesn't show the login on the screen

Comment: Ok let me take a close look. I will try to help you with this. Just give me couple of minutes.

Comment: I added the code in a way that I meant :) Try this out. If it dose not work post the code again and I will run it at my end and fix it. I have been doing network programming now for 10 years or so and this takes some time to get used to. When you get a good feel for it there are so many cool things you can do regarding IoT.

Comment: Reposted changed code, server still doesn't display the login of client  :(

Comment: I will run the code and see what is going on.

Comment: I found the problem, you are using readline and readline needs new line, therefore all that was needed is to add "\n" to out.write(... + "\n");. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh God. It works now. Thans a lot for help and your time :)

Comment: Btw do you have any tips how to send a message from client to all the other clients beside the one writing it/

Comment: That's a good question, I don't have anything right out of my head, but you should give everyone and id and store it in the ClientHandler. But first off all start implementing input read for the client and output write for ClientHandler.

Comment: If you found the answer to be satisfying do you mind marking it as the answer and close the question.

Comment: Sorry forgot about it, ive just done that, thanks a lot :)